# find exact value from user input to csv file content

Tags: javascript, csv, input, find, match

I have a simple HTML file with input text id="ERP", I want the user to be able to find the exact match to the CSV file content. Here is the code I have been trying to fix. This searches the CSV file but returns result not exactly as the value entered from input box, Example, input box value = "CH-134", the out-put will show data for "CH-134-DT" how can I make the search result exactly the same as the input? Thank you in advance.

```
    var DB = new Array();
    function MakeDB() { DB = CSV.split('\n'); }

    function CSVsearch(dbInfo) {
    var posn = -1;
    for (i=0; i<DB.length; i++) {
    tmp = DB[i];
    if (tmp.indexOf(dbInfo) != -1) { posn = i; break; } 
    }
    if (posn == -1) { alert('No matching result from the file'); }
    else { document.getElementById('tblDisplay').innerHTML = displayAsTable(DB[posn]); }
    }
    function displayAsTable(info) {
    var table = '<table border="1" width="75%" bgColor="F5F5F5" borderColor="FFFFFF">';
    var ary = info.split(',');
    table += '<tr align="left"><th align="left">'+ary.join('</tr><th align="left">')+'</td></tr>';
    table += '</table>';
    return table;
    }
    function resetthis() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use the [Javascript str.match(regexp) function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and a regular expression, instead of using the str.indexOf(searchValue) function.

So in your case, I'd do something like:

```
var regex = '/\b' + dbInfo + '\b/g';
var matches = tmp.match(regex);
if (matches.length > 0) 
{ ... }
```

Just replace the '\b' above with whatever you'd expect your incoming data to be separated by. For example, if you expect to find CH-134 is in your dataset with spaces before and after, you can leave the '\b' there. If it is in your dataset with commas, you can replace '\b' with ','. Or if you only know what terminates the word you're trying to match, you can leave off the first '\b' from the regex. For example, you could do something like:

```
//finds occurences of dbInfo with anything before it, but only a comma after it
var regex = '/' + dbInfo + ',/g';

//finds occurences of dbInfo with a word break before it, and no hyphen after it
var regex = '/\b' + dbInfo + '[^-]/g';
```

You'll probably be able to come up with a better, more precise, regular expression for your needs. My favorite site for playing with and testing out regular expressions is http://regexr.com/

Good luck!

Comment: well, regex dint work for me or is it that because the entry from the user value is totally random, it doesn't have any pattern that I could cover on regex, value can have spaces, special characters, numbers and such. What I do really need is to match exact result from what ever the user input is, is there a way to do it on jscript?

Comment: @April yes, the user input is random...but what does the data set you're searching look like? For example, if the user inputs "CH-134", what *separates* "CH-134" from another piece of data, like "CH-134-DT"? If it's commas (I'm assuming this because it is a CSV), then when the user inputs "CH-134", in the javascript, add a comma to search on. You can do this with your current strategy. Just say {dbInfo = dbInfo + ','} Then you'll match the first occurence of "CH-134," which is different than "CH-134-DT", because of the comma.

Comment: wow! thanks! you are accurate about tis! {dbInfo = dbInfo + ','} I also notice something wrong about this code is this: <b> if (tmp.indexOf(dbInfo) != -1) { posn = i; break; } <b> I replaced the 'if' to 'while' as the loop stops when it found similar (not exact value) of the user input, and I did as you said, I added ',' to it and it worked perfectly! I am accepting your answer and thanks a lot for helping me to get there!

Answer (score 0):

tadaaa, as according to Seth, I added the dbInfo + ',' and simply put the 'while' so the loop wont stop when the search hits a similar value. WoohOooo

```
    var DB = new Array();
    function MakeDB() { DB = CSV.split('\n'); }

    function CSVsearch(dbInfo) {
    var posn = -1;
    var input = document.getElementById('ERP').value;
    for (i=0; i<DB.length; i++) {
    tmp = DB[i]; //ROW DATA
    while (tmp.indexOf(dbInfo+',') != -1) { posn = i; break; } 
    }
    var data = DB[posn];
    if (posn >=0) { (alert('RECORD FOUND!\nERP: ' + dbInfo));
    document.getElementById('tblDisplay').innerHTML = displayAsTable(data); }
    else { (alert ('NO RECORD FOUND')); }
    }
    function displayAsTable(info) {
    var table = '<table border="1" width="75%" bgColor="F5F5F5" borderColor="FFFFFF">';
    var ary = info.split(',');
    table += '<tr align="left"><th align="left">'+ary.join('</tr><th align="left">')+'</td></tr>';
    table += '</table>';
    return table;
    }
    function resetthis() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
```